# Initializing properties of objects with call signatures inside other objects

Tags: typescript

I have an object with a call signature and property:

```
type MyDescribedFunction = {
    description: string
    () => boolean
}
```

I know that you can't create an instance of this is the normal way. So this is how I'm doing it (the compiler stays happy after assigning the description property)

```
const functionImpl: MyDescribedFunction = () => { return true }
functionImpl.description = "Foo" // Compiler error only if this line is commented out
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this exact same thing, but do it with `functionImpl` being a property of an object.

```
type MyObjType = {
    name: string
    fun: MyDescribedFunction
}

const myObjInstance: MyObjType = { 
    name: "Foo",
    fun: () => { // compiler error: Property 'description' is missing in type '() => true' but required in type 'MyDescribedFunction'
        return true
    }
}
myObjInstance.fun.description = "Bar" // This line does not alleviate the error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function which constructs a `MyDescribedFunction` for you.

```
type MyDescribedFunction = {
    description: string
    (): boolean
}

function newFunctionImpl(): MyDescribedFunction {
  const functionImpl: MyDescribedFunction = () => { return true }
  functionImpl.description = "Foo"
  return functionImpl
}

type MyObjType = {
    name: string
    fun: MyDescribedFunction
}

const myObjInstance: MyObjType = { 
    name: "Foo",
    fun: newFunctionImpl()
}
```

Comment: Had to do some tweaking to make it appropriate for my actual use case, but this general idea worked great. Thanks!